# SQL - Delete Statement Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Can someone take a look at my delete statement and let me know why this might not be working? As you can see the Add Statement is here as well...This works perfectly...I traded out a statement in the DELETE and it does not work.

**Add Statement Works Perfect:**

```
<?php
include 'include/dbconnect.php';
$usr_id=$_POST['id'];
$usr_name=$_POST['username'];
$item_id=$_POST['itemid'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM useritems where userid='$usr_id' And itemid='$item_id'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
//echo 'incoming data '.$result;
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) <1) {



$sql = "insert into useritems (userid,username,itemid) values ('$usr_id','$usr_name','$item_id')";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
echo 'success';
}
else
echo 'fail';
```

**Delete Statement does not:**

```
?>
<?php
include 'include/dbconnect.php';
$usr_id=$_POST['id'];
$usr_name=$_POST['username'];
$item_id=$_POST['itemid'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM useritems where userid='$usr_id' And itemid='$item_id'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
//echo 'incoming data '.$result;
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) <1) {
    $sql = "DELETE FROM useritems WHERE userid='$usr_id' AND itemid='$item_id'";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    echo 'success';
}
else
echo 'fail';
?>
```

Comment: Yeah I am scratching my head...it isn't taking action though

Comment: Nothing was echo'ed at all...no action actually was taken

Comment: It's not echoing success or fail?

Comment: What does `echo mysqli_num_rows($result)` show?

Comment: Nothing...it doesn't do anything...I added the page above that has an alert, works perfectly...I have done nothing but copy the php file it points too (updated in the field)...change the phrasing in the alert, and added a delete statement....and it doesn't even show the alert anymore

Comment: Check the PHP error log on the server, the script may not be running.

Answer (score 0):

You only go in to the DELETE Statement if you found num rows less then 1. That means : no ROWS:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) <1) {
```

Change it to

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) >0) {
```

Comment: No change...going to try the one below